# Error when using a forked gem (active_admin) from Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, rubygems, activeadmin, sprockets

I'm experiencing a really weird issue. When I fork the active_admin gem and use the forked, unchanged version it gives me the following error:

```
Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new
/Users/Victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/active_admin-916ecdd04e3c/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js has already been required

Extracted source (around line #12):

9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag style.path, style.options %>
10:   <% end %>
11:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.each do |path| %>
12:     <%= javascript_include_tag path %>
13:   <% end %>
14: 
15:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

When I use the original version there are no errors. How is this possible if the two versions are identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.you can remove the line

```
//= require_directory ./
```

in

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/active_admin-916ecdd04e3c/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/application.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove active_admin.js from your app/assets/javascripts folder - it looks like it is no longer needed.